# javascript tabs to display the same info

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: Current status]

I have  the above leaderboard with the two tabs 'Leaderboard1' and 'Leaderboard 2'.
Leaderboard1 button displays the above the leaderboard as shown in pic.How can I have the same leaderboard to be displayed when I click the "leaderboard" 2 tab .
The content of the second leaderboard will be differnt,which I will take care of later on.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">

    <ul class="tab-group">
      <li class="tab active"><a href="#leaderboard">LeaderBoard 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#login">LeaderBoard 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="signup">

        <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">

          <ol>
            <li>
              <mark>Shivam Sharma</mark>
              <small>315</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Deepa B</mark>
              <small>301</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
              <small>292</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
              <small>245</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
              <small>203</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
              <small>203</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
              <small>245</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
              <small>203</small>
            </li>

          </ol>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div id="login">
        <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">

          <ol>
            <li>
              <mark>Shivam Sharma</mark>
              <small>315</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Deepa B</mark>
              <small>301</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
              <small>292</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
              <small>245</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
              <small>203</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
              <small>203</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
              <small>245</small>
            </li>
            <li>
              <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
              <small>203</small>
            </li>

          </ol>
        </div>
        <!-- leaderboard -->

      </div>
      <!-- login id div -->
    </div>
    <!-- tab-content -->

  </div>
  <!-- /form -->




  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Fiddle link for it : https://jsfiddle.net/Zedhmem/ju0xr8of/1/

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more? If you want another tab which references the actual leaderboard you just add another: <li class="tab active"><a href="#leaderboard">LeaderBoard</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#leaderboard">LeaderBoard 2</a></li>

Comment: Thank you .I want to see the same leaderboard when the click the other tab.In the fiddle link,lets say the Medaltally tab.

Comment: Fiddle link is not working please update for futher help

Comment: You mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/ju0xr8of/11/

Comment: @VenkateshKonatham Sry fr the trouble.I updated it now.

Comment: @Sergiodiaz53 Thank you.But i dont want it within the same div. i.e for the second tab the values of the leaderboard will be different.So it has to be under a different div.

Comment: The source you have placed in fiddler and in the screenshot is different. I am trying to understand what exactly need to be done. Main pain with your question is to understand the problem

Comment: problem is that I just want a similar leaderboard with different data to be displayed when I click the second tab.

Comment: ok got it. Let me check it

Comment: This? http://jsfiddle.net/ju0xr8of/12/ sorry if I'm not understanding you.

Comment: Nothing to be sry. I hav written a clear question here again. Thank you for helping me out   . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234892/display-leaderboard-using-javascript-tabs

Comment: I have added a answer below please check it and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your request i have updated below source please check latest one

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var _this = $(this);
                    var block = _this.attr('href');
                    $(".tab").removeClass("active");
                    _this.parent().addClass("active");
                    $(".leadboardcontent").hide();
                    $(block).fadeIn();
                });
            });
```

```css
 *, *:before, *:after {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            html {
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }

            body {
                background: #c1bdba;
                font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
            }

            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #1ab188;
                -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
                transition: .5s ease;
            }
            a:hover {
                color: #179b77;
            }

            .form {
                background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
                padding: 10px;
                max-width: 305px;
                margin: 40px auto;
                border-radius: 20px;
                box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
                padding-bottom: 1px;
            }

            .tab-group {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0 ;
            }
            .tab-group:after {
                content: "";
                display: table;
                clear: both;
            }
            .tab-group li a {
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #a0b3b0;
                font-size: 20px;
                float: left;
                width: 50%;
                text-align: center;
                cursor: pointer;
                transition: .5s ease;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            .tab-group li a:hover {
                background: #ff8566;
                color: #ffffff;
            }

            .tab-group .active a {
                background: #ff5c33;
                color: #ffffff;
            }

            .tab-content > div:last-child {
                display: none;
            }

            /*--------------------
            Body
            --------------------*/
            *,
            *::before,
            *::after {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            body {
                min-height: 650px;
                height: 200px;
                margin: 0;
                background: -webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
                background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
                color: #fff;
                font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            }

            /*--------------------
            Leaderboard
            --------------------*/
            .leaderboard {
                -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
                transform: translate(0%, 0%);
                width: 285px;

                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a404d, #181c26);
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a404d, #181c26);
                border-radius: 10px;
                box-shadow: 0 7px 30px rgba(62, 9, 11, 0.3);
            }
            .leaderboard h1 {
                font-size: 18px;
                color: #e1e1e1;
                padding: 12px 13px 18px;
            }
            .leaderboard h1 svg {
                width: 25px;
                height: 26px;
                position: relative;
                top: 3px;
                margin-right: 6px;
                vertical-align: baseline;
            }
            .leaderboard ol {
                counter-reset: leaderboard;
                padding:0px !important;

            }
            .leaderboard ol li {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
                font-size: 14px;
                counter-increment: leaderboard;
                padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
                cursor: pointer;
                -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
                backface-visibility: hidden;
                -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
                transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
                list-style: none;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li::before {
                content: counter(leaderboard);
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 2;
                top: 15px;
                left: 15px;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                line-height: 20px;
                color: #c24448;
                background: #fff;
                border-radius: 20px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li mark {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 2;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
                margin: 0;
                background: none;
                color: #fff;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li mark::before, .leaderboard ol li mark::after {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                bottom: -11px;
                left: -9px;
                border-top: 10px solid #c24448;
                border-left: 10px solid transparent;
                -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
                transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li mark::after {
                left: auto;
                right: -9px;
                border-left: none;
                border-right: 10px solid transparent;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li small {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 2;
                display: block;
                text-align: right;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li::after {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: #fa6855;
                box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
                -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
                transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1) {
                background: #fa6855;
                border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1)::after {
                background: #fa6855;
                border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) {
                background: #e0574f;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2)::after {
                background: #e0574f;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::after {
                border-top: 6px solid #ba4741;
                bottom: -7px;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) {
                background: #d7514d;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3)::after {
                background: #d7514d;
                box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::after {
                border-top: 2px solid #b0433f;
                bottom: -3px;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) {
                background: #cd4b4b;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4)::after {
                background: #cd4b4b;
                box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
                top: -7px;
                bottom: auto;
                border-top: none;
                border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) {
                background: #cd4b4b;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5)::after {
                background: #cd4b4b;
                box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
                top: -7px;
                bottom: auto;
                border-top: none;
                border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) {
                background: #cd4b4b;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6)::after {
                background: #cd4b4b;
                box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
                top: -7px;
                bottom: auto;
                border-top: none;
                border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) {
                background: #cd4b4b;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7)::after {
                background: #cd4b4b;
                box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
                top: -7px;
                bottom: auto;
                border-top: none;
                border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) {
                background: #c24448;
                border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8)::after {
                background: #c24448;
                box-shadow: 0 -2.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
                border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) mark::after {
                top: -9px;
                bottom: auto;
                border-top: none;
                border-bottom: 8px solid #993639;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:hover {
                z-index: 2;
                overflow: visible;
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:hover::after {
                opacity: 1;
                -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
                transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
            }
            .leaderboard ol li:hover mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:hover mark::after {
                opacity: 1;
                -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
                transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
            }
```

```html
 <div class="form">

            <ul class="tab-group">
                <li class="tab active"><a href="#weeklylb">Weekly LB</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#overalllb">Overall LB</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#defaulters">Defaulters</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#co-workers">Co-Workers</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="weeklylb" class="leadboardcontent">

                    <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">

                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Weekly LB</mark>
                                <small>315</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Brandon Barnes</mark>
                                <small>301</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
                                <small>292</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
                                <small>245</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
                                <small>203</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
                                <small>203</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
                                <small>245</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
                                <small>203</small>
                            </li>

                        </ol>
                    </div>


                    <svg style="display: none;">
                    <symbol id="cup" x="0px" y="0px"
                            width="25px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 25 26" enable-background="new 0 0 25 26" xml:space="preserve">
                        <path fill="#F26856" d="M21.215,1.428c-0.744,0-1.438,0.213-2.024,0.579V0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865H6.69
                              C6.204,0,5.81,0.387,5.81,0.865v1.142C5.224,1.641,4.53,1.428,3.785,1.428C1.698,1.428,0,3.097,0,5.148
                              C0,7.2,1.698,8.869,3.785,8.869h1.453c0.315,0,0.572,0.252,0.572,0.562c0,0.311-0.257,0.563-0.572,0.563
                              c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865c0.421,0,0.816-0.111,1.158-0.303
                              c0.318,0.865,0.761,1.647,1.318,2.31c0.686,0.814,1.515,1.425,2.433,1.808c-0.04,0.487-0.154,1.349-0.481,2.191
                              c-0.591,1.519-1.564,2.257-2.975,2.257H5.238c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865v4.283c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865h14.525
                              c0.485,0,0.88-0.388,0.88-0.865v-4.283c0-0.478-0.395-0.865-0.88-0.865h-1.452c-1.411,0-2.385-0.738-2.975-2.257
                              c-0.328-0.843-0.441-1.704-0.482-2.191c0.918-0.383,1.748-0.993,2.434-1.808c0.557-0.663,1-1.445,1.318-2.31
                              c0.342,0.192,0.736,0.303,1.157,0.303c0.486,0,0.88-0.387,0.88-0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865
                              c-0.315,0-0.572-0.252-0.572-0.563c0-0.31,0.257-0.562,0.572-0.562h1.452C23.303,8.869,25,7.2,25,5.148
                              C25,3.097,23.303,1.428,21.215,1.428z M5.238,7.138H3.785c-1.116,0-2.024-0.893-2.024-1.99c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99
                              c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99v2.06C5.627,7.163,5.435,7.138,5.238,7.138z M18.883,21.717v2.553H6.118v-2.553H18.883
                              L18.883,21.717z M13.673,18.301c0.248,0.65,0.566,1.214,0.947,1.686h-4.24c0.381-0.472,0.699-1.035,0.947-1.686
                              c0.33-0.865,0.479-1.723,0.545-2.327c0.207,0.021,0.416,0.033,0.627,0.033c0.211,0,0.42-0.013,0.627-0.033
                              C13.195,16.578,13.344,17.436,13.673,18.301z M12.5,14.276c-2.856,0-4.93-2.638-4.93-6.273V1.73h9.859v6.273
                              C17.43,11.638,15.357,14.276,12.5,14.276z M21.215,7.138h-1.452c-0.197,0-0.39,0.024-0.572,0.07v-2.06
                              c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99C23.241,6.246,22.333,7.138,21.215,7.138z"/>
                    </symbol>
                    </svg>
                </div> 
                <div id="overalllb" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
                    <div class="leaderboard">

                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Overall LB</mark>
                                <small>3115</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Brandon Barnes1</mark>
                                <small>3101</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Raymond Knight1</mark>
                                <small>2192</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Trevor McCormick1</mark>
                                <small>2145</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Andrew Fox1</mark>
                                <small>2103</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>And1rew Fox1</mark>
                                <small>2103</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Tre1vor McCormick1</mark>
                                <small>2145</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Andrew Fox1</mark>
                                <small>2103</small>
                            </li>

                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- login tab end defaulters -->
                <div id="defaulters" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
                    <div class="leaderboard">

                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Defaulters</mark>
                                <small>3115</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Brandon Barnes2</mark>
                                <small>31012</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Raymond Knight2</mark>
                                <small>21922</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Trevor McCormick2</mark>
                                <small>21452</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
                                <small>21032</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>And1rew Fox2</mark>
                                <small>21032</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Tre1vor McCormick2</mark>
                                <small>21452</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
                                <small>21032</small>
                            </li>

                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- login tab end co-workers -->
                <div id="co-workers" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
                    <div class="leaderboard">

                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <mark>co-workers</mark>
                                <small>3115</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Brandon Barnes2</mark>
                                <small>31012</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Raymond Knight2</mark>
                                <small>21922</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Trevor McCormick2</mark>
                                <small>21452</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
                                <small>21032</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>And1rew Fox2</mark>
                                <small>21032</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Tre1vor McCormick2</mark>
                                <small>21452</small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
                                <small>21032</small>
                            </li>

                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </div><!-- tab-content -->

        </div> <!-- /form -->

        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.You a genius.I wanted to make some changes here.I was trying to include two more tabs.Plz help me .I have alredy troubled u so mch though. Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/sharma1331/hxxmg9t1/

Comment: I am checking it.

Comment: I have changed the above source please check it. Its dynamic

Comment: Thanks a ton bro.Much appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the above leaderboard with the two tabs 'Leaderboard1' and 'Leaderboard 2'.

i don't see them now https://gyazo.com/d54bd3cca356246f58ffbfa2238a23ef

Comment: sry for the trouble.plz look at the picture link.The fiddle link has different names,but the problem is neverthelessd the same.